# What is a 21 + 3113 Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word adheres to a certain rule I call it a 21 + 3113 Word™.

[image]

Text-only version in CSV form:

```
"MINUTELY","BACON"
"INFLECTS","TOUGH"
"ZESTFUL","TASTEFUL"
"UTENSIL","INTRODUCE"
"JUSTICE","ENCHANTED"
"CUTIES","ROBIN"
"INVEST","CONFUSE"
"SWIVEL","GIRAFFE"
"FILET","PRICE"
"UNITS","YOKE"
"UNTIMELY","GATHER"
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why they’re called what they are yet, but

> 21 + 3113 Words all have no enclosures in the word (for example, A and O have an enclosure but E, I, U do not.) Non-21+3113 Words have at least one enclosure.

A possible solution could be that

> 21, 3, 11, 3 translates to U-CKC; neither 21, 3113, U, or CKC have any enclosures either.

Thanks to @Stiv for noticing that

> 21 + 3113 translates to U+3113, which is the Unicode for [this symbol](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3113/index.htm) which also doesn’t have any enclosures.

Comment: Name possibly connected to [this symbol](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3113/index.htm) which shares same property??

Comment: I like that much better — nice job, @Stiv !